# No Parenthesis in Rails - Good Style?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, styles

When I first started with ruby/rails and noticed that you don't need to put parenthesis, I recall thinking "no way I'll do that!".

But now I kind of like it.

So the question is, is that good style? Or should I stick to using parenthesis?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downvotes are probably because SO is technically not a good forum for this kind of question - apparently SO community likes clear, answerable, discrete, objective questions, not more general style or technique questions like this. But I love questions like these, so here goes.

Since working with Ruby various little style questions like this drive me absolutely crazy, which is stupid because they're not that big of a deal. But the Ruby community seems obsessed with style questions, maybe it just comes with the territory of having an extremely expressive language.

**My answer:**

I try to orient everything around making my code as intelligible as possible, without making it unreasonably long. If I'm struggling between two styles, I'll almost always come down on the style that I think will be easier for a more novice developer to understand in the future.

I omit parentheses when either there's no arguments, or when the argument "flows naturally" after the method name. So if the method is describing an action and the first parameter is the object of that method, it's beautiful to omit the parentheses. Like this:

```
create :user, name: "Topher"
raise "Problem!" unless @thingy.is_a? String
render partial: "filters"
```

But often the first parameter of the method is a hash of options or is an incidental value or something other than "the object of the action being taken". In these cases, I usually find it looks wrong / jarring to leave out the parentheses. Like in these cases:

```
@user.disable!(force: true)
@entries.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

And of course, if you're chaining methods together (like building up an ActiveRecord call), you need to include the parentheses if any params are present, so the question becomes moot.

**A more general answer:**

If you haven't already, read [the Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide), from start to finish, a couple times. Some rules will appeal to you, some will repulse you, but exposing yourself to it will get you familiar with the styles and patterns used by many many other Rubyists (who debate about those styles ad nauseum) and when you're confronted with similar situations, you'll be more conscious of the different ways to approach it and what tradeoffs of those different styles might be.

Comment: Great answer. I also now realize my question was a bit silly. Also thanks for including the style guide.

Comment: I happen to think this sort of question is more important and more useful to other readers than the typical "Zomg heres my code why not work HELP" you mostly see around here, but I also know that most SO veterans disagree about that. Anyway, glad I could help!